# What is the expression, var=1.e12?

Tags: fortran, var, exponent

I have been trying to understand a FORTRAN code, which has the following expression:

> var=1.e12

What is the meaning of this expression and its equivalent in FORTRAN 90/95

Comment: I'd guess a variable named 'var' gets assigned a real value of 1.e12 (10^12) . I think it will also  be Fortran 95

Comment: This is not only valid Fortran 95, but valid almost any other language, including pocket calculators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elementary, my dear Watson:

`1.e12` is a floating point numeral; in this case, it's value is `1.0 * 10^12`.

> its equivalent in fortran90

Um, I think that's valid f90.